# Transcluding Multiple Infoboxes in MediaWiki (CSS)

Tags: html, css, mediawiki, infobox

I'm trying to set up some simple Infoboxes on my MediaWiki install.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801082/how-do-you-make-infoboxes-in-mediawiki/48122703#48122703). Here is my current code (it's exactly the same as from that question, and I do have ParserFunctions):

```
Template Page
```

```
<div class="infobox">
<div class="infobox-title">{{{title|{{PAGENAME}}}}}</div>{{#if:{{{image|}}}|
<div class="infobox-image">[[File:{{PAGENAME:{{{image}}}}}|300px]]</div>}}
<table class="infobox-table">{{#if:{{{param1|}}}|<tr>
    <th>Parameter 1</th>
    <td>{{{param1}}}</td>
</tr>}}{{#if:{{{param2|}}}|<tr>
    <th>Parameter 2</th>
    <td>{{{param2}}}</td>
</tr>}}{{#if:{{{param3|}}}|<tr>
    <th>Parameter 3</th>
    <td>{{{param3}}}</td>
</tr>}}{{#if:{{{param4|}}}|<tr>
    <th>Parameter 4</th>
    <td>{{{param4}}}</td>
</tr>}}{{#if:{{{param5|}}}|<tr>
    <th>Parameter 5</th>
    <td>{{{param5}}}</td>
</tr>}}</table>
</div>
```

```
Relevant CSS (Part of Common.css)
```

```
.infobox {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 400px;
}
.infobox-title {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.infobox-image {
    text-align: center;
}
.infobox-table th {
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
}
.infobox-table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This works fine until I want to transclude multiple pages that have infoboxes into a single page.

When I do that, the infoboxes stack horizontally instead of vertically. There are several HTML elements (mostly `<p>`) in between the infoboxes due to how MediaWiki writes the HTMl after transclusion.

[image: Transcluded Infoboxes]

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I change.

The only thing I can think of is to somehow make a section on the right side of the page that is used to hold each infobox, but I don't know how we could make something like that for every page on the wiki, and only have it hold specifically infoboxes. Honestly I might be looking in the wrong direction completely.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert `<br clear="all" />` before transcluded pages.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new div around the whole thing in a div called infobox-container and these css settings and got it working

```
.infobox-container {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.infobox {
    background: #333;
    color:#c1c1c1;
    border: 1px solid #db8200;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
 .infobox-title {
   font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
 .infobox-image {
    text-align: center;
}
 .infobox-table th {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
    background: #4c4c4c;
}
 .infobox-table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```